# Trying to boost nodejs performance

Tags: node.js

Hi my Nodejs app loads DynamoDb data, there is 14 items, Instead of memcache or redis I tried this to improve server performance, I am not aware how long my Nodejs can keep this data??? or I am not aware will it make any issue later??? Should I use this for long time

```
// it loads data from dynamodb
const {getAllItems} = require('./server/dbinteraction'); 
let cacheData;

app.get('/loadalldata', async (req,res)=>{

      let data;

      if(cacheData){
            data = cacheData
        }else{
            data = await getAllItems()
        }

    res.send(data)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider the following things:

**If data is not growing over the period and small in volume:**

1. You can do as you are doing right now.
2. Make sure data is loaded properly if the server restart
3. Check this out [lowdb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lowdb)

**If data is growing over the period and not so large**

1. You can use Redis as a caching layer.
2. Don't try to cache everything.

In your case, data volume is very small, You can just store data in JSON file and can manipulate it.

[Read this out](https://dzone.com/articles/introducing-amp-assimilating-caching-quick-read-fo) It will help you understand much better.

Comment: In my case there will be max 30-40 objects only

Comment: Yeah you can store in just JSON file and can use `lowdb` if you want API available on data

Comment: On start, you would load data in memory from the JSON file when the server start and it will be in memory as long as the server (Nodejs) is running.